# gstreamer pipeline to mix three audio source?

Tags: audio, gstreamer

This mixing of the two files:

> gst-launch uridecodebin uri=file:///tmp/file1.mp3 ! adder name = m ! autoaudiosink uridecodebin uri=file:///tmp/file2.mp3 ! audioconvert ! m.

How to mix the 3 files ?

Answer (score 2):

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file:///tmp/file1.mp3 ! audioconvert ! adder name = m ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink \
               uridecodebin uri=file:///tmp/file2.mp3 ! audioconvert ! m. \
               uridecodebin uri=file:///tmp/file3.mp3 ! audioconvert ! m.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gst-launch-0.10 adder name=mix ! alsasink filesrc location=file1.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! mix. filesrc location=file2.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! mix. filesrc location=file3.wav ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! mix.
```

Surely isn't the best way. But, is a little start.

Answer (score -1):

replace "alsasink" with "wavenc ! filesink location= output.wav" ?